# Laravelで、外部キー制約の処理で SQLSTATE[23000] エラーが出て、マイグレートできません。

Tags: php, laravel

**users テーブル**
https://gyazo.com/831e6d98dfc12e266db09b3a0db6bd11

**lectures テーブル**
https://gyazo.com/c2626070a76bc14e555d89c7c3d7dfdf

上記2つのテーブルがあり、
lecturesの「user_id」カラムと users の「id」カラムとを紐付けたいので、
このようにしました。

**add_foreign_to_lectures_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddForeignToLecturesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('lectures', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('lectures', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('lectures_user_id_foreign');
        });
    }
}
```

しかし、このようなエラーが返ってきてしまいました。

> ```
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bbl`.`#sql-51e8_25`, CONSTRAINT `lectures_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `lectures` add constraint `lectures_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`)   
>    references `users` (`id`))
> ```

https://gyazo.com/bf3045cf3582c6084526b01719cdd6ce

これについて、解決策を教えていただければ幸いですm(_ _)m

Comment: すでにデータが入っている場合は、データはきれいに（外部キー制約がつけれるように）しましたか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！投稿したデータがいくつもあるのですが、外部キー制約を付ける場合は、それらのデータをすべて削除する必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 外部キー制約から外れているデータがあると、制約をつけることができません。既存のデータの状態を追記いただけますか？

Comment: 既存のデータの状態とは、こちらでよろしいのでしょうか？？ https://gyazo.com/f0797c5e5e2b1b45379c5b48ddc37dc6

Answer (score 1):

今回の原因は
「users.idに存在しないデータがlectures.user_idに存在している」からです。

対処法としては
「lectures.user_idに存在しているusers.idに存在しないデータ」を削除するか置き換えないといけません。

外部キー制約は
「参照元フィールドに存在するデータのみ参照先フィールドのデータに存在できる」
という仕様です。

今回の場合は
「users.idに存在するデータのみlectures.user_idに存在できる」
という形になります。
ただしそもそも
「users.idに存在しないデータがlectures.user_idに存在している」
場合その外部キーを設定することすらできません。
今回のエラーもそのようなメッセージです。

じゃあどのようなデータが存在しているかは実際データをみて調査してみてください。
またどのような対応を取るかもシステムの仕様に依存するので対処の方法も変わります。

- 整合性が取れないデータをdeleteするか
- usersにデータを追加する
- lectures.user_idにnullを代入する

のいずれかになると思います

ちなみに
コメントのデータの中身を見るとlectures.user_idに0が存在するものがありそうですね。
lectures.user_idが必須条件でない場合は0ではなくてNULLを入れるか疑似データとしてusers.idが0のデータを必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

なんとかなります。過去ログに似たようなエラーとその答えが書いていました。

Comment: その過去ログへのリンクや、解決法の要約があると他の方の参考になります。回答は後からでも [edit] できますので、もしよろしければお願いいたします。